# How to exchange sqlite3 executable with latest version on my raspberry pi?

Tags: raspberry-pi, python3, sqlite

I needed the generated columns feature that has just been added to sqlite3 in the latest release. I managed to get it working in my python application on windows by simply replacing the relevant sqlite3.dll with a new downloaded binary. I am now in the process of porting my app to a raspberry pi (debian) but as a linux noob I'm having trouble finding the sqlite3 executable. Bearing in mind all the permissions and owners stuff which makes my head spin; I'm wondering, Can this be done on linux and if so how?

Answer (score 0):

To find the location of an executable on linux use `which` or `whereis`. However, it's recommended to use package managers to update software. debian uses apt.

```
# sudo apt-get update
# sudo apt-get install sqlite3
```

```
# which ls
/usr/bin/ls
# whereis ls
ls: /usr/bin/ls /bin/ls /home/james/ls.txt /usr/share/man/man1/ls.1.gz /usr/share/man/man1p/ls.1p.gz
```

Comment: My bad, I should have made clear the version I'm after isn't yet available via package managers. apt-get returns sqlite3 v3.27. I need v3.31. However following your heads up regards which and whereis I located the relevant file.